# How can I init a UIButton subclass?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I tried to add a double value to a subclass of UIButton in Swift. I tried all kind of inits and get and set options, but I couldn’t get it to work.

So I started with this:

```
class CVSTButton : UIButton {
    var cvstPosition: Double

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Then I tried:

```
class CVSTButton : UIButton {
    var cvstPosition: Double {
        get {
            return self.cvstPosition
        }
        set {
            self.cvstPosition = newValue
        }

    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
   }
}
```

What’s is wrong here?

Answer (score 275):

With Swift 3, according to your needs, you may choose one of the **seven following code snippets** to solve your problem.

---

#### 1. Create your `UIButton` subclass with a custom initializer

This solution allows you to create instances of your `UIButton` subclass with the appropriate value for your property. With this solution, you can only create instances of your UIButton subclass programmatically.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var myValue: Int

    required init(value: Int = 0) {
        // set myValue before super.init is called
        self.myValue = value

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        // set other operations after super.init, if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = CustomButton(value: 0)
        // let button = CustomButton() // also works
        button.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)

        // auto layout
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        print(button.myValue) // prints 0
    }

}
```

---

#### 2. Create your `UIButton` subclass with a convenience initializer

This solution allows you to create instances of your `UIButton` subclass with the appropriate value for your property. With this solution, you can only create instances of your `UIButton` subclass programmatically.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var myValue: Int

    convenience init(squareOf value: Int) {
        self.init(value: value * value)
    }

    required init(value: Int = 0) {
        // set myValue before super.init is called
        self.myValue = value

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        // set other operations after super.init, if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = CustomButton(squareOf: 10)
        // let button = CustomButton(value: 100) // also works
        button.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)

        // auto layout
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        print(button.myValue) // prints 100
    }

}
```

---

#### 3. Create your `UIButton` subclass with `init(frame: CGRect)` initializer

With this solution, you can only create instances of your `UIButton` subclass programmatically.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var myValue: Int

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // set myValue before super.init is called
        self.myValue = 0

        super.init(frame: frame)

        // set other operations after super.init, if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let button = CustomButton(frame: .zero)
        //let button = CustomButton() // also works
        button.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)

        // auto layout
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        print(button.myValue) // prints 0
    }

}
```

---

#### 4. Create your `UIButton` subclass with `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` initializer

With this solution, you can create instances of your `UIButton` subclass from Storyboard.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var myValue: Int

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // set myValue before super.init is called
        self.myValue = 0

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // set other operations after super.init, if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: CustomButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(button.myValue) // prints 0
    }

}
```

---

#### 5. Create your `UIButton` subclass with `init(frame: CGRect)` and `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` initializers

With this solution, you can create instances of your `UIButton` subclass programmatically or from Storyboard.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var myValue: Int

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        // set myValue before super.init is called
        self.myValue = 0

        super.init(frame: frame)

        // set other operations after super.init, if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        // set myValue before super.init is called
        self.myValue = 0

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // set other operations after super.init if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

}
```

---

#### 6. Create your `UIButton` subclass with a default property value for your property

As an alternative to the previous solutions, you can assign an initial value to your property outside of the initializers.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var myValue: Int = 0

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // set other operations after super.init, if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // set other operations after super.init if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

}
```

---

#### 7. Create your `UIButton` subclass with your property having an optional type

If you don't want to / can't set a default value to your property when your button is created, you must set your property type as an optional.

```
import UIKit

class CustomButton: UIButton {

    var myValue: Int? = nil

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        // set other operations after super.init, if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        // set other operations after super.init if required
        backgroundColor = .red
    }

}
```

Comment: I like that you gave scenarios of why to use each code snippet. Phenomenal response - wish more questions were answered like this.

Comment: How to call convenience init() if the button is an outlet?

Comment: In the usage part of snippet 3, where a frame is used as the initialiser, it would be clearer to use something like `CustomButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 200, height: 50))` rather than `CustomButton(frame: .zero)` and auto layout

Answer (score 12):

You need two things there -- (1) `cvstPosition` needs an initial value, either in the declaration or in the `init` before you call `super.init()`. (2) That call to `fatalError` is put in so you don't forget to implement the initializer -- it’s basically an on-purpose crash. Delete!

Setting the initial value in the declaration, there isn’t any need for an `init`:

```
class CVSTButton : UIButton {
    var cvstPosition: Double = 0
}
```

Or setting the initial value in the initializer:

```
class CVSTButton : UIButton {
    var cvstPosition: Double

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        cvstPosition = 0

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah great so i just have to declare and give the variable a init value!

Comment: You need a question mark after `init` in Swift 2.2, so `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {`

Answer (score 8):

### Swift >= 2.2:

Since this version subclassing the `UIButton`, makes your button to have `.custom` type.

#### Swift 2:

```
convenience init(type buttonType: UIButtonType) {
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

    // this button be automatically .Custom
}
```

#### Swift:

```
override class func buttonWithType(buttonType: UIButtonType) -> AnyObject {
    let button = super.buttonWithType(buttonType) as! UIButton
    // your default code
    return button
}
```

Comment: You want to insert 'public' in there. I.e.:     override public class func

Comment: Not, of course.
Read that public is the scope between projects.

Comment: Re *"...your subclass becomes with type .Custom default."*: That is close to incomprehensible. Can you [fix](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32084565/edit) it? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 4):

**Note: I'm using Swift 3 in [Xcode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) 8.3.3**

This is a simple and easy workaround I've been using when needing to add custom properties and methods to a `UIButton`:

```
class CVSTButton: UIButton {

    var cvstPosition: Double

    static func button(withCVSTPosition cvstPosition: Double) -> CVSTButton {

        let button = CVSTButton(type: .detailDisclosure) // You may adjust the initializer used to suit your needs.

        button.cvstPosition = cvstPosition // Then you can simply set the the properties (which are passed as arguments to the factor/class method)

        return button

    }

}
```

To use it:

```
let cvstButton = CVSTButton.button(withCVSTPosition: 2.0)
```