# How to assign a custom class programmatically in swift for UIButton

Tags: swift, uibutton, interface-builder

I have created a UIButton with system type

```
let systemButton = UIButton(type: .system)
```

I have a subclass of **UIButton** named **SSRadioButton**.

[image]
Instead of doing this thing in IB, I want to do it programmatically. All suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you connecting it to a ViewController as an IBOutlet?

Comment: No. My view controller will have nothing. Everything I need to do programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to make it programmatically, simply implement:

```
// make sure to setup the frame as it should...
let myButton = SSRadioButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 50))

// OR, for your case:
//let myButton = SSRadioButton(type: .system)

myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
// setup all pther needed properties...

view.addSubview(myButton)
```

Target of the button:

```
func myButtonPressed() {
    print(#function)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
let systemButton = UIButton(type: .system)
```

Use,

```
let systemButton = SSRadioButton()
```

and do further activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all details about UIButton () declaration in [stack overflow: how to init a UIButton subclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27079681/how-to-init-a-uibutton-subclass). It is a very complete answer and I do not have anything to add.